# How could fix "Volley client NetworkError in Android?

Tags: android, android-volley

I turn off my firewall, but persist the problem, com.android.volley.NetworkError

Also I implemented in the manifest, but nothing

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {

//declare variables
Button btnlogin;
TextView tvcreateuser;
private ViewPager screenPager;
RequestQueue rq;
JsonRequest jrq;
EditText cajaUser,cajaPwd;
Button btnConsultar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //start variables
    btnlogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
    tvcreateuser = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcreateuser);
    cajaUser = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtUser);
    cajaPwd =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtPwd);
    btnConsultar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSesion);
    rq = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    btnConsultar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            iniciarSesion();
        }
    });



    //functions
    login();
    createuser();
}

private void createuser() {
    tvcreateuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CreateUserActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

private void login() {
    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,PrincipalActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Nada perrito"+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Se encontro el usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    User usuario = new User();
    JSONArray jsonArray = response.optJSONArray("datos");
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;

    try {
        jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        usuario.setUser(jsonObject.optString("user"));
        usuario.setPwd(jsonObject.optString("pwd"));
        usuario.setNames(jsonObject.optString("names"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void iniciarSesion(){
    String url = "http://10.62.2.71/login/sesion.php?user="+cajaUser.getText().toString()+
            "&pwd="+cajaPwd.getText().toString();
    jrq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
    rq.add(jrq);
}
}
```

I turn off my firewall, but persist the problem, com.android.volley.NetworkError

Comment: Did add `INTERNET PERMISSION` in AndroidManifest.xml file? Server (API) is active? IP address is proper?

Comment: add the body of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest ....>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application>
    ....


</manifest>
```

Comment: HI, firs of all thanks for answering me, but I have this and nothing  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />